# How do I enforce passthrough props in TypeScript (in React) when passing a component as prop as well?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have 3 components (`CompA`, `CompB`, and `CompC`), and `CompC` invokes the `CompB` component, which invokes the `CompA` component:

```
type PropsCompA = { param1: string };
const CompA = (props: PropsCompA) => (
  <p>{props.param1}</p>
)
type PropsCompA2 = { param2: string };
const CompA2 = (props: PropsCompA2) => (
  <p>{props.param2}</p>
)

type PropsCompB = {
  comp: React.StatelessComponent<any>;
  subProps: Record<string, any>;
};
const CompB = (props: PropsCompB) => (
  <props.comp { ...props.subProps }/>
)

const CompC = () => (
  <>
    <CompB subProps={{ param1: 'hello' }} comp={CompA} />
    <CompB subProps={{ param2: 'hello' }} comp={CompA2} />
  </>
)
```

Is there a way to ensure that when invoking `CompB`, that the `subProbs` passed to that component align with what's expected for the properties for the `comp` property. I.e, right now `CompA` expects props as `{param1: string}`, and `CompA2` expects props as `{param2: string}`. However, when changing the code to this:

```
const CompC = () => (
  <>
    <CompB subProps={{ param33: 'hello' }} comp={CompA} />
    <CompB subProps={{ param44: 'hello' }} comp={CompA2} />
  </>
)
```

TypeScript won't throw an error. Is there a way make it so TypeScript would throw an error? I assume it has something to do with this line:

```
type PropsCompB = {
  comp: React.StatelessComponent<any>;
  subProps: Record<string, any>;
};
```

But I'm not quite sure. I'm fairly familiar with Generics, and have been playing around with this using Generics for a while, but still haven't quite been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `CompB` and `PropsCompB` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the passed in sub-component props:

```
type PropsCompB<T> = {
    comp: React.StatelessComponent<T>;
    subProps: T;
};

const CompB = <T,>(props: PropsCompB<T>) => <props.comp {...props.subProps} />
```

```
const CompC = () => (
    <>
        <CompB subProps={{ param1: 'hello' }} comp={CompA} /> // ✅
        <CompB subProps={{ param2: 'hello' }} comp={CompA2} /> // ✅
        <CompB subProps={{ param33: 'hello' }} comp={CompA} /> // ❌
        <CompB subProps={{ param44: 'hello' }} comp={CompA2} /> // ❌ 
    </>
)
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGcBhXMAQTgF44BvOGBRQUIAIwAuOExhRgAOwDmcAL4BuUmgjyZcNuC68AFGEZMpDCM32cAlDwB8cI6Thu4AHjAO%20pq0wA6IRFxFQ8Aem9SWwpqWktrdg4AJh5%20QWFRZKkZOSVVDS0deBsUtJMzCzNS5PtuJxd3T29fMyDMkGSwyIdo8ioaemr2ACEPABUnXj5Xdy1wKWR0GACAZRgUGCQAGyQmVnZtJHkYCYcNJqYAVwAjBPM4cY11TW1dGxG0iYAaBwr-Kr%20D5nOoNWZuLxteZgfgBOF%20ZgBa53MwqODhXoxV7FPTsFjlUHOcGeXpNJoeD7SW73bh8ATBUSSOAAcgAFjtthBmao0dDaaU0Rj0eE4IBQcmJ5MpyJpdIyIWyLPZ2053JUvPY-KSXXRTnCIvFZPcFNGVJR-lp9I6AGYrVI2RyuTy4Hy%20AKdcK4IAZcglRql1LMFrlogALMG7UqVU6XTVBbqRZ64MSIpigA)

Answer (score 0):

So the Record will take any string value as a key in your example. [Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt). To change this, you can type the key rather than allow it to be any string.

What you can do is something like this:

```
type ParamKeys = "param1" | "param2";
type PropsCompB = {
  comp: React.StatelessComponent<any>;
  subProps: Record<ParamKeys, any>;
};
```